# Do immigration official check return ticket status, whether it is cancelled or not?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas

One must have return ticket at immigration. Do immigration official check return ticket status, whether it is cancelled or not?

Comment: immigration officials (and airline staff, who won't board you if they feel you won't be admitted) vary wildly. Some will simply take your word for the existence of a ticket, or accept something nonofficial like a printout of your itinerary that you made yourself. Others will demand an official thing from an airline and perhaps they actually check that you didn't cancel it yet. Asking about the officials in just one country (ideally in just one airport) might make this answerable, but as written it is far too broad.

Comment: @KateGregory Really?  I would find it exceedingly unlikely that an immigration official anywhere in the world would check whether a ticket is really valid, unless you've already aroused a lot of other suspicions.

Comment: "One must have return ticket at immigration." That certainly not true everywhere. You must convince the immigration officer that you'll leave at the appropriate time and possessing a return ticket may be part of that. But this question is unanswerably broad. There are over 200 countries in the world and most of them have their own rules and policies.

Comment: @DavidRicherby furthermore, in some places, it's only true for certain visitors.  For example, in the US, visitors with B visas have no return ticket requirement, nor do visa waiver program visitors arriving by land.  VWP visitors arriving by air or sea do need one, but I don't think it is checked routinely.

Answer (score 3):

Do they? Usually not.

Can they? Yes. If you’ve presented concerns that you may not have been truthful or that you may have immigration or other intent, then immigration officers have very broad powers - including verifying your itinerary with airline, hotels, your receiving party, your workplace, etc.

Their computer may or may not have a direct link to the airline ticketing systems, but it’s easy enough for them to verify by phoning the airline.

If you’re at any risk for this, buy a refundable ticket that you can cancel at any time or date such as after you’ve entered. Or simply don’t lie to immigration officers. Lying to an immigration officer can lead to a multi-year or lifetime ban.